# Construct string pattern for two different types of lines

Tags: pattern-matching, string-manipulation

I need to increase my understanding of string patterns.  My specific problem is that I have a definition of a type in SystemVerilog that has lines that are either single-bit or multi-bit.  I want the names and sizes of these fields.

An example:

```
someDefinition = "typedef struct packed {
    logic         data_valid_ms;    // some data valid
    logic         ms_word_ms;       // set to indicate this is the ms word
    logic         overflow_ms;      // set if overflowed
    logic         init;             // 0 = something; 1 = something else
    logic   [3:0] active_widgies;         
    logic  [20:0] t_tmeasured;             
    logic   [2:0] unused_ms;               
    logic         data_valid_ls;    // repeated data valid
    logic         ms_word_ls;       // clear to indicate this is not the ms (ie is the ls word)
    logic         overflow_ls;      // set if overflowed
    logic  [20:0] t_d;            
    logic         occ4;       
    logic         gcss1;      
    logic         gcss4;      
    logic   [1:0] s_phase;         
    logic         dest_internal;    
    logic         r_s;            
    logic         unused_ls;               
  } status_reg_t;";
```

I tried multiple ways of processing the entire string and had to settle for splitting the string and then considering each line.  I imagine that there has to be a way to do this on the whole input string, but maybe not.

This code works, but it only does so by considering each line:

```
NamesAndSizesFromDefinition[def_String] := Block[{
    lines = StringSplit[def, EndOfLine],
    multiBitDefinition,
    singleBitDefinition
    },
   multiBitDefinition =    
    Shortest[__ ~~ "logic" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "[" ~~ upperLimit__ ~~ 
       ":" ~~ lowerLimit__ ~~ "]" ~~ ___ ~~ aName__ ~~ 
       ";"] :> {StringTrim@aName, 
      ToExpression[upperLimit] - ToExpression[lowerLimit] + 1};
   singleBitDefinition = 
    Shortest[ __ ~~ "logic" ~~ Whitespace ~~ aName__ ~~ 
       ";"] :> {StringTrim@aName, 1};
   Flatten[If[StringContainsQ[#, "["],
       StringCases[#, multiBitDefinition],
       StringCases[#, singleBitDefinition]
       ] & /@ Take[lines, {2, -2}], 1]
   ];
```

If I run this on the previous definition, I get this:

```
NamesAndSizesFromDefinition[someDefinition]
(*{{"data_valid_ms", 1}, {"ms_word_ms", 1}, {"overflow_ms", 1}, {"init",
   1}, {"active_widgies", 4}, {"t_tmeasured", 21}, {"unused_ms", 
  3}, {"data_valid_ls", 1}, {"ms_word_ls", 1}, {"overflow_ls", 
  1}, {"t_d", 21}, {"occ4", 1}, {"gcss1", 1}, {"gcss4", 
  1}, {"s_phase", 2}, {"dest_internal", 1}, {"r_s", 1}, {"unused_ls", 
  1}}*)
```

This is what I want, but again, my string pattern ignorance is blocking me from a single solution without line splitting.

I had tried this:

```
NamesAndSizesFromDefinition[def_String] := With[{
   keyword = "logic",
   lines = StringSplit[def, "\n"],
   multiBitDefinition =    
    Shortest[
      EndOfLine ~~ __ ~~ "logic" ~~ Whitespace ~~ "[" ~~ 
       upperLimit__ ~~ ":" ~~ lowerLimit__ ~~ "]" ~~ ___ ~~ aName__ ~~
        ";" ~~ __ ~~ EndOfLine] :> {StringTrim@aName, 
      ToExpression[upperLimit] - ToExpression[lowerLimit] + 1},
   singleBitDefinition = 
    Shortest[ 
      EndOfLine ~~ __ ~~ "logic" ~~ Whitespace ~~ 
       Except[Characters["["]] ~~ aName__ ~~ ";" ~~ __ ~~ 
       EndOfLine] :> {StringTrim@aName, 1}
   },
  StringCases[
   def,(*Reverse@*){multiBitDefinition, singleBitDefinition}]
  ]
```

It gives different answers depending on whether I put the single or multiBitDefinition first in StringCases so clearly, I haven't figured out how to differentiate the two string patterns depending on whether there are brackets in the string.

I would appreciate knowing how this might be done.

Comment: @MarcoB - thank you for editing to make the formatting nicer.

Comment: You are very welcome!